# data with date field default null return '01-01-1970'

Tags: postgresql, date, null

How to solve this issue?

I have made default value for date field in Postgres DB when inserted is null, but when I display in datagrid, it will be displayed 01-01-1970

Comment: Is it displaying as '01-01-1970' as in the question title, or '01-01-2017' as in the question body?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` of the table in question and the `insert` statements you used. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: sorry wrong type, already edited

Comment: I don't think the problem here is postgresql. i think your client may be mapping null values to 0 (seconds) wich in unix time means 01/01/1970.

Comment: how to display 0000-00-00 instead of 01/01/1970?